# Showing convergence under a specific metric

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

> Show:
>   $(a_n)\to a$ in $(X,d)$ if and only if $(a_n)\to a$ in $(X,d_1)$, where $d_1(x,y)=\ln(1+d(x,y))$.

So far we have:

Proof:
$\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $n\geq N$,
$d(a_n,a)<\varepsilon$. Well, $\ln(1+d(a_n,a))<\ln(1+\varepsilon)$.

I'm stuck here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to be somewhat more specific about your "specific metric"! What is $d$, and what is $d_1$?

Comment: $d$ is given to be an arbitrary metric on a space $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Using that $\ln(1 + t) < t$ for all $t > 0$, you can write $\ln(1 + d(a_n,a)) < \ln(1 + \epsilon) < \epsilon$. So you have one direction. For the reverse direction, suppose $a_n \to a$ in $(X,d_1)$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then $\ln(1 + \epsilon) > 0$. So there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $d_1(a_n,a) < \ln(1 + \epsilon)$ for all $n \ge k$. The inequality $d_1(a_n,a) < \ln(1 + \epsilon)$ is equivalent to the inequality $d(a_n,a) < \epsilon$. So $d(a_n,a) < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge k$, and hence $a_n \to a$ in $(X,d)$.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!!